# Blur a field without using jQuery

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jqlite

I would like to (unit) test my AngularJS app without resorting to using jQuery, as jQuery will replace jqLite and in the real app jQuery won't be available either.
There are real differences between jQuery and jqLite, so having jQuery available to AngularJS in the unit tests is a risk.

Most of my tests work fine without jQuery now, but I need to blur a field, something I can only find out how to do using jQuery. How would I do that in Javascript in a cross browser fashion?

UPDATE: After receiving the answer I solved it using triggerHandler() but not in the directive itself but in the unit test like this:

```
it("should set the blur state on blur", function() {
    angular.element(elm[0][0]).triggerHandler("blur");
    expect($rootScope.passwordblur).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: You can also use angular UI @ http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to try directives:

```
app.directive('blurable', function () {        
        return {
            link: function(scope, element) {               
                element.bind("blur" , function(e){
                    // blur happens
                });
                scope.triggerBlur = function(){
                    element.triggerHandler("blur");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

So now in your `scope` you can run this `triggerBlur` method for "manual" blur.
Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/wPqRqh

Comment: nice, never seen that function before!

Comment: @Maarten but i don't know if this style is a good practice in a context of unit-testing...

Comment: Think it should be ok; the unit is tested with a real event, only the trigger is simulated but there is always a certain agree of simulation with stubs etc... If others think otherwise please let me know